# What are the packages in a setup.py?

Tags: python, package, distutils

I was reading [this article](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html), and it had this code:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='Distutils',
      version='1.0',
      description='Python Distribution Utilities',
      author='Greg Ward',
      author_email='gward@python.net',
      url='https://www.python.org/sigs/distutils-sig/',
      packages=['distutils', 'distutils.command'],
     )
```

And I am wondering what the `packages` are. Are they folders/directories? or a type of file? or it it a zip or py file?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straight from your own link.

([Relevant section](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages))

> The `packages` option tells the Distutils to process (build, distribute, install, etc.) all pure Python modules found in each package mentioned in the `packages` list.
>
> ...
>
> Thus, when you say `packages = ['foo']` in your setup script, you are promising that the Distutils will find a file `foo/__init__.py`